# Bug with ShinyFeedback not displaying correct label with File Input

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building an app that takes excel files as an input. To protect against errors, I first check if the file is an .xls or .xslx, and then I check if it contains the right content based on the sheet names.
I'm encountering that the first time I upload the right file, the app works as expected:

[image]

But when I hit 'browse' and try to upload again, I get this:

[image]

It only shows the right label on the first time.
This doesn't happen if I upload an excel file with the wrong info multiple times

[image]

If I then try to upload a different type of file, I get this:

[image]

Here's the simple code

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(tools)
library(shinyFeedback)
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(),
  
  fileInput("file", "upload file", multiple = FALSE),
  tableOutput("data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <-  reactive({
    
    req(input$file)
    path <- input$file$datapath
    good_file <- file_ext(path) == "xls" || file_ext(path) == "xlsx"
    feedbackDanger(inputId = "file",
                   show=!good_file,
                   color = "orange",
                   text = "Upload only .xls or .xlsx files")
    req(good_file)
    good_sheet <- "Special Sheet" %in% excel_sheets(path)
    feedbackDanger(inputId = "file",
                   show=!good_sheet,
                   color = "#E6007E",
                   text = "File must contain the special sheet'")
    req(good_sheet)
    read_excel(path)
    
  })
  
  output$data = renderTable(data())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The req() 's are indeed working because no output gets generated until both good_file and good_sheet are TRUE, just a note

Comment: Unable to replicate even after I've added the missing library calls.  And your `reactive` will always be empty since it returns `NULL`.

Comment: I added the correct library calls. I had them loaded before writing this.  Do you the correct label after uploading multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but perhaps this is due to the fact that the two feedbacks are the same.

Here is a solution:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    
    req(input$file) 
    hideFeedback("file") # hide feedback, if any
    path <- input$file$datapath
    good_file <- file_ext(path) == "xls" || file_ext(path) == "xlsx"
    if(!good_file){
      showFeedbackDanger(inputId = "file",
                         color = "orange",
                         text = "Upload only .xls or .xlsx files")
    }
    req(good_file)
    good_sheet <- "Special Sheet" %in% excel_sheets(path)
    if(!good_sheet){
      showFeedbackDanger(inputId = "file",
                         color = "#E6007E",
                         text = "File must contain the special sheet'")
    }
    req(good_sheet)
    read_excel(path)
  })
  
  output$data = renderTable(data())
}
```